# how to return in a recurssive fn in java

Tags: java

Actually my aim is to find the super no for eg i will be given 2 values n,k where n=148 and k =3 so i have to form p = 148148148 then add digits of p until i get a single no (ans = 3) this is what i have tried.......

```
import java.util.*;

public class RecurrsiveDigitSum {

     public int check(int n) {
         int s = 0;
         int d;

         while(n>0) {
             d = n%10;
             s = s+d;
             n = n/10;
             System.out.println(s);
        }

        if(s/10 !=0){
            check(s);
        }

        return s;
     }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int k = scan.nextInt();
        int sum;
        RecurrsiveDigitSum obj = new RecurrsiveDigitSum();
        sum =  obj.check(n);
        System.out.println(sum);
        sum = sum * k;
        System.out.println(sum);
        int s1 = obj.check(sum);
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
}
```

but the problem here is that even if my s = 4 finally its just returning the first value of s that has been found so pls help me friends

Answer (score 2):

you must put return before recursive calling.

```
if(s/10 !=0){
    return check(s);
}
```

If you don't put it, the result of calling function will be loss and the result of s will be returned instead of check(s).

I've improved your solution little bit.

```
public int check(int n) {
    int s = 0;

    while(n>0) {
        s += n%10;
        n /= 10;
    }

    if(s/10 != 0){
        return check(s);
    }

    return s;
 }
```